# Unity 3D Scripting - Trying to limit camera zooming

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

been working on the camera for uni project that needs to be able to zoom using the mousewheel, I got that much working at least:

```
public class ScrollWheel : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float speed;


    void Update()
    {
        float scroll = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
        transform.LookAt(target);
        transform.Translate(0, 0, scroll * speed, Space.Self);
    }
}
```

However, I need to be able to limit how much the camera can move along the Z axis, otherwise they can zoom into and under the map, as well as scroll upwards infinately.

Struggling a little with this one, not gonna lie. Just want to limit the scroll between -20 and -190 on the Z axis.

Tried a few pieces of code but they refused to work alongside the prior, ive found very few people that are having the same issue, and none of them are using this apparent method, which to be frank I'm barely familiar with myself.

Comment: It would make sense to check if z is within the range to move or not.. surely?

Answer (score 0):

Put this line of code after your translation:

```
transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.Z, -minZoom, maxZoom));
```

And of course make sure you give minZoom and maxZoom their appropriate values (minZoom=-190, maxZoom=-20)